# How do you symbolize a feature class layer in ArcMap 10 based on one attribute's value and then another attribute's value?

Tags: arcgis-10.0, arcmap, symbology, layers

I currently have a point feature class that has a couple of attributes that I want to use to symbolize its layer.  One of the attributes is called *ExceedsTolerance*, which either has "Y" or "N" for its value.  The other attribute is called *Measure*, which has the values -2, -1, or anything from 0 and greater.

I know that I can create a layer definition that has different symbols for unique values for each attribute.  For instance, I can have a black box for *Measure* when the value is -2, an orange circle for when the value is -1, and a blue circle for when it is greater than or equal to 0.  The same idea goes for *ExceedsTolerance*.

What I would like, however, is to have it where it shows a certain symbol when *ExceedsTolerance* is "Y" no matter what the *Measure* is, but when *ExceedsTolerance* is "N" to show whatever I have set for *Measure*.  I can somewhat do this with the Multiple Attributes section of the Symbology tab in the Layer Properties, but I can't do it with the case where *Measure* is greater than 0 and *ExceedsTolerance* is "N".  How would this work in ArcMap and is it possible?

Comment: You'll need to create a new attribute that aggregates these values.  Use the field calculator with logic in the code block that differentiates between different symbologies with a value.  If you could post an example of your data I may be able to help you.

Comment: That definitely sounds like an option as I needed something that would be conditional as I'd have to use that layer file in a lot of projects.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

You should be able to use the "Unique value, many" option, see caption below.

[image]

Comment: I thought about that, but then I couldn't have a single symbol for when the _Measure_ is >= 0 and _ExceedsTolerance_ is Y.  Since this wouldn't be a one-time deal, I'd like to have it where it would be a certain way any time the measure is >= 0.

Comment: You can add each possible value here, then just select all of the values exceeds= Y and right click on the selected values an dchoos group. now edit the label to say exceeds = Y. Or use the quantities and create classes,